# Prevent "&" from being converted to "&amp;" in Jinja

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am iterating over a dictionary in Python. The values that contain `&` are converted to `&amp;`.  How Do I stop that?  It shows on the web page like this:

```
Hobbies &amp; Leisure
```

My code looks like this:

```
{% for k,v  in vertical.iteritems() %}
    {value: '{{k}}', text: "{{v}}"},
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try the `safe` Jinja filter.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#safe

```
{% for k, v in vertical.iteritems() %}
    {value: '{{ k|safe }}', text: "{{ v|safe }}"},
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `safe` by default so as to not have to write "|safe" many times?